# OCZ RevoDrive only recognized on first boot

Tags: ssd

I have an OCZ Revodrive which works fine... for the first time I boot the machine.

The motherboard is an Abit Fatal1ty FP-IN9 SLI (I detailed some of my findings at: https://www.martineve.com/2011/01/21/ocz-revodrive-on-abit-fatal1ty-fp-in9-sli/) and, as I said, if the power has been disconnected from the machine for 30 minutes, the Revodrive is recognized just fine. However, if I reboot the box or shutdown and power on again, the device is not recognized. I have to physically disconnect the power cable for 30 minutes after which time it will work.

Any ideas? Really annoying when I need to reboot :/

Best,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the firmware for the Revodrive? I remember reading a changelog for some SandForce firmware update that stated it fixed an error where the drive wouldn't appear if you power cycled the computer too quickly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but: http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?79091-Revodrive-Firmware-Now-update-able-in-1.11 -- no user updatable firmware :*